# error when retrieving current configuration of: Resource: "apps/v1, GroupVersionKind: "apps/v1, Kind=Deployment" Name: "", Namespace: "default"

Tags: kubernetes

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
  labels:
    app: mongodb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector: 
    matchLabels:
      app: mongodb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongodb
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mongodb
        image: mongo
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
        env:
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongodb-secret
              key: mongo-root-username
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongodb-secret
              key: mongo-root-password 
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata: 
  name: mongodb-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: mongodb
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017


my secret file:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mongodb-secret
type: Opaque 
data:
    mongo-root-username: dXNlcm5hbWU=
    mongo-root-password: cGFzc3dvcmQ=
```

I'm getting an error as below:

error: error when retrieving current configuration of:
Resource: "apps/v1, Resource=deployments", GroupVersionKind: "apps/v1, Kind=Deployment"
Name: "", Namespace: "default"
from server for: "mongo.yaml": resource name may not be empty

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your Deployment at the top level doesn't have a `metadata: { name: }`.

Comment: can you please show me how can add it? @DavidMaze

Comment: Your Service and Secret already correctly have a name.  It's one additional field under the top-level `metadata:`.